# How to Get Old String After Replce String in Regex in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string str = "Computer & Web Solution / deva/sasasa@ww";
 String stre = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "-");
```

My Result = `Computer-Web-Solution-deva-sasasa-ww`
How to get   `"Computer & Web Solution / deva/sasasa@ww"` (Old String )  with Regex Or other Code

Comment: what means javascript in this case?

Comment: From the old variable you can get the old string back unless you are not disposing the old value.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are talking about a `Match`?
then you need to define the regex like

```
var reg = new Regex( @"([^0-9a-zA-Z])+");
```

then you will be able to get the original text for each match by

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("Computer & Web Solution / deva/sasasa@ww");
foreach(var m in matches){
    //m.Result("$1")  this is the value of each matched original text
}
```